# AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'rmvApp'

Tags: python, namespaces, argparse

I am trying to add 2 options to my script, "add" and "rmv," but when I use the add option I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bsony/bin/moveVM", line 240, in 
    elif(args.rmvApp):
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'rmvApp'

Vice versa when I use the rmv option I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bsony/bin/moveVM", line 238, in 
    if (args.addApp):
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'addApp'

The relevant code snipped is below:

```
#Set main parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A scirpt to add, move or remove     apps file the various apps file')
sub_parser = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')

#Set add parser
addApp = sub_parser.add_parser('add', help='Add new app to apps file')
addApp.add_argument('-a', '--add', dest='addApp', type=str, help='The application you want to add to the apps file')

#Set remove parser
rmvApp = sub_parser.add_parser('rmv', help='Remove app from apps file')
rmvApp.add_argument('-r', '--rmv', dest='rmvApp', type=str, help='The application you want to remove from the apps file')

args = parser.parse_args()

#Dictionary to store variables making it easier to pass between functions
appDict = {
    "environment": "",
    "appToAdd": "",
    "appToRmv": "",
    "appToMove": "",
    "realEnv": "",
    "newHost": "",
    "newVMID": "",
    "oldAppLine": "",
    "newAppLine": "",
    "oldPRLines": []
}

appsFileList = [] #empty list to ingest apps file to

#Get evironment name for apps file
appDict["environment"] = raw_input('What environment would you like to move an app from? (dev, pt, pr): ').lower()

if (appDict["environment"] not in ["dev", "ppe", "pt", "pr"]):
    print("\nYou did not enter a valid environment...exiting...")
    exit()

#Set apps file location
userID = getpass.getuser() #gets linux user ID to use in appsFilePath

#check for add or remove flags and call function if flags are used
if (args.addApp):
    addApp(appsFileList, appDict, appsFilePath, userID)

if(args.rmvApp):
    rmvApp(appsFileList, appDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to see which command was specified before you can access command-specific arguments.  So you could do:

```
if args.command == 'add':
    print(args.addApp)
elif args.command == 'rmv':
    print(args.rmvApp)
else:
    print("No command specified")
```

Only the sub-parser arguments for the specified command will be present.